# How should i configure my couchone instance?

Tags: security, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am having a wee bit of trouble configuring my couchone instance. I have setup a admin user. But I am still unable to modify any configuration options

> http://[your-app-name-here].couchone.com/_utils/config.html

Throws this error:

> An error occurred retrieving/updating
>   the server configuration: This config
>   variable is read-only

Anyone have any experience using couchone hosting? How do I make it more secure? i.e:

1. No anonymous user interaction with
   my couchone instance.
2. No accessing futon without basic authentication (similar to cloudant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They had to read-only a few settings based n large amounts of User-Error in setting things up.

See here [Couchio Forums](http://forums.couch.io/discussion/6/authentication/p1)